# How to "fixup" git rerere resolution

Tags: git, git-rerere

My workflow usually consists of `merge -> resolve conflicts -> commit -> debug during compilation -> fixup commit`. In this way I make dirty merge with clearing afterwards. If I enable `rerere` I would always have dirty resolutions recorded. How to bypass this problem? Is there a way to fix `rerere` resolution by following commit?

Comment: What you are doing is perfect! May be no other way exists.

Comment: Stop thinking merges are dirty and you’ll be a lot happier.

Comment: This process of broken merges also affect other workflows, like seeing what broke the build using `git bisect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clumsy but what have I did for my last big bad merge.

At first I have checkout my branch to before merge state in tmp branch.
Then run similar merge. Then do following process:

```
for F in `git show $FIXCOMMIT --stat | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +7 | head -n -1`; do
    git checkout -m $F
    git rerere forget $F
    cp $FIXED/$F ./$F
done
```

Where FIXCOMMIT is commit with fixes. And FIXED is workingtree with FIXCOMMIT state.

As a lesson I think that one shouldn't commit merge before compilation.

Answer (score 0):

My workflow typically consist of:

> Make changes -> test -> commit ->  make more changes -> test -> commit -> repeat.

This gives me multiple local commits that together comprise what need to be done. When I feel done I run:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~[nr_of_commits_i_created]
```

And I make sure to fixup all but the first one. The first one I either keep as it is or reword it one last time. Now I end up with 1 commit containing all my changes. I rebase on my master branch, solve any conflicts and push my changes.

This way I never really have to deal with merging.

I realize that this does not directly answer your question.